# Как отправлять сообщения в лс в telethon?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

Написал такого бота:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, errors
    import asyncio
    
    
    class UserBot:
        async def ConnectUser(self, id, hash, name):
            try:
                self.client = TelegramClient(name, id, hash)
                await self.client.connect()
                if not await self.client.is_user_authorized():  # If further authentication is needed via text
                    await self.client.send_code_request("+380960389178")
                    print('Further authentication required in order to log in, a code has been sent to the phone number.')
                    await self.client.sign_in("+380960389178", input('Enter the code: '))
                print(await self.client.is_user_authorized())
                print(f"Аккаунт {name} успешно инициализирован")
    
            except:
                print(f"Ошибка при инициализиции аккаунта {name}")
        
        async def SendMessage(self, message, user):
            print("Отправка...")
            await self.client.send_message(user, message)
            print("Отправлино!")
    
    myuser = UserBot()
    asyncio.run(myuser.ConnectUser("", "", ""))
    asyncio.run(myuser.SendMessage("Hello", "me"))
```

Вроде все нормально, ошибок нет, но происходит следуйщие:

```
True
Аккаунт anytestword успешно инициализирован
Отправка...
```

и все, дальше ничего не происходит, просто отправка. Что с этим сделать можно?